# Fetch data from HTML by net/html

Tags: html, go, parsing, web-scraping

I saw that the performance of net/html is 2-3 times faster than GoQuery and I want to rewrite the parser module on it. Need to get the data underlined in the screenshot. Now result is "nil"

```
resp, err := http.Get(link)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
var result string
doc, err := html.Parse(resp.Body)
resp.Body.Close()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

if doc.Type == html.ElementNode && doc.Data == "profile-data__count-number" {
    for _, a := range doc.Attr {
        if a.Key == "em" {
            result = a.Val
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(result)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Note that *class* is an HTML **attribute**, so looking for `class="profile-data__count-number"` in `Node.Data` will never result in a match. You should instead look for it in [`Node.Attr`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/html#Node.Attr).

And if I'm not mistaken the tokenizer ought to be even less wasteful than the parser, so doing something like the following should give you a little bit better performance, I think:

```golang
func getCounts(respBody io.Reader) (counts []string, err error) {
    z := html.NewTokenizer(respBody)
    for {
        if z.Next() == html.ErrorToken {
            if err := z.Err(); err != io.EOF {
                return nil, err
            }   
            break
        }

        t := z.Token()
        if t.Type == html.StartTagToken && t.Data == "div" {
            for _, a := range t.Attr {
                if a.Key == "class" && a.Val == "profile-data__count-number" {
                    if z.Next() == html.TextToken {
                        counts = append(counts, z.Token().Data)
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return counts, nil
}
```

Comment: Not working, print empty data

Comment: @hey you'll need to provide a [mcve], otherwise I'm not sure what you're doing wrong. See this working example: https://go.dev/play/p/OdSbF7KGSP9

Comment: @hey there was one issue in the original answer that caused a compile time error, namely the *unused* variable `i`, I've removed that from the answer now.

Comment: I do it to, not working

Comment: As I've already said, without a [mcve], it's not possible for me to know what you're doing wrong and suggest an accurate fix.

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/smkLAqL7URP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250139/discussion-between-mkopriva-and-hey).

Comment: Can I ask u 1 more help in chat please, about the same question

Comment: @hey sure, I'm in the chat